# Is there a keyboard shortcut to select the entire current line in Notepad++?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++, microsoft-onenote

Microsoft OneNote has a handy shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) that I use all the time to select an entire line. 
And if you click it a second time it selects the entire document.

I really would like to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> as shortcut in Notepad++ to select the current line, but its default is to select the entire document.  Is there a way to make it select only the entire current line?

Comment: Just to add, Microsoft OneNote can also select entire document with `Ctrl + A` shortcut. Just keep pressing `Ctrl` and press `A` multiple times, it expands selection from line to section to entire document.

Comment: Also to add that Visual Studio defaults to the current line when nothing is selected. I've become so used to simply pressing Ctrl-C or Ctrl-X anywhere in a line, that the lack of this functionality in Notepad++ constantly surprises me, The fact that N++ currently does nothing in this situation, seems to leave it wide open for implementation.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Press <kbd>Home</kbd> then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>.

<kbd>End</kbd> then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> can also be used. If you need to select the line from the **very beginning** instead of the *first indented character*, press <kbd>Home</kbd> twice.

You can also record this as a macro and then set a shortcut to that macro. However <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> is used as *select all* in almost all text editors and textboxes, thus changing it could make things more confusing. Use another shortcut instead

If you just want to **copy/cut/delete** the lines, there are already shortcuts for you:

- Line delete <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>
- Line cut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>
- Line copy <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> (changed to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> in newer Notepad++)

There are also other actions without default shortcuts like line transpose, line join, line duplicate... Just select *Settings* > *Shortcut mapper* > *Scintilla commands*, select `SCI_LINETRANSPOSE` / `SCI_LINEDUPLICATE` / `SCI_LINESJOIN`... and assign them.

If <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> doesn't work for you then it's because the shortcut has been assigned to 2 different features, causing a conflict as [PryrtCJ answered below](https://superuser.com/a/1038591/241386). In newer Notepad++ line copy has been changed to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, and a shortcut conflict warning has also been added, making life a bit easier

[image]

See [Lists of default mouse and keyboard shortcuts for Notepad++ and some plugins](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Keyboard_And_Mouse_Shortcuts)

If you're using a mouse, single click the line number on the left or triple click in the line also do the trick.

Comment: I can confirm that CTRL+Shift+T *** DOES NOT WORK!!! *** Windows 10, NPP 6.8.6. My results are that NPP is trying to create a new file for some reason. I'm not sure why. Possibly related to a plugin? Hope this helps somebody. I've seen this "solution" on 3 different website. At least for me, it does NOT work.

Comment: Ctrl-Shift-T did not work for me either.  Win7, NPP 6.8.3. 
Single-clicking the line number and then Ctrl-C was the fastest way for me.

Comment: @CodeSlayer2010 did you try opening the Scintilla commands like I said? Maybe your shortcuts have been modified somehow or you're using a different language, hence different shortcut. Just change `SCI_LINECOPY` to whatever you want.

Comment: @dvdhns while typing how is that faster than a single shortcut when you needs to move your hand to find the mouse then press shortcut?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: Thanks for your reply. I did not try that because I didn't want to go through the effort of remapping my keys. But, it does sound like the scintilla commands could be a good place to check to see if something else may have altered them.

Comment: @CodeSlayer2010 you should read PeterCJ's answer below. Maybe just a conflicting situation like he said

Answer (score 8):

In NPP7.5.1 `SCI_LINECOPY` is assigned to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>

So you can use  <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to copy current line to the clipboard

Answer (score 7):

For those for whom the accepted answer doesn't work: I just answered a similar concern [in the Notepad++ Community](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/11279/ctrl-shift-t-not-copying-current-line-to-clipboard/2).  Basically, there are two commands associated with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> shortcut simultaneously, and the other appears to be taking preference.

If you would prefer <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to reference `SCI_LINECOPY`, find the conflicting command (for example, `Shortcut Mapper` >> `Main menu` >> `Restore Recent Closed File`, which is what's causing the conflict in my copy of NPP), select <kbd>Modify</kbd>, then change the dropdown letter from <kbd>T</kbd> to <kbd>NONE</kbd> and hit <kbd>OK</kbd>.  Assuming there are no more conflicts, the shortcut will revert to `SCI_LINECOPY`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Good Input, Can you please explain the significance of SCI commands than the ones on main menu?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not an expert at the Scintilla commands.  I just found two actions mapped to the same keyboard shortcut, and figured out which one to disable so the shortcut would do what _I_ want it to. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Just click 3 times to a word or line

Comment: clicking isn't a keyboard shortcut. And even if the mouse can be used then **just a single click on the left of the line number is enough**. No need for a triple click

Answer (score 1):

In my system, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> selects the current line.

Program version: x64 Portable 8.5.2. System: Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make it via Macro.

1. Go to Macro > Start recording
2. Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and tap Down <kbd>↓</kbd> to mark for example 10 lines . And delete them.
3. Go to Macro > Stop Recording. *Now your macro is recorded, you can save it for using in the future .*
4. Go to Macro > Save Current Recording Macro... . And save it with a name .
5. Move cursor to line that you want to delete lines after that.Then go to Macro > Run A Macro Multiple Times... . And select your macro and run it N times that you want.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19161262/select-range-of-lines-in-notepad

Comment: Q: How can I select a line using the keyboard?  A: Here's a way to delete 10 lines.  You'll need to click the mouse a few times whenever you use it.     ***What?***

Comment: @G-Man Since you can assign a shortcut to macros this solution is perfectly viable. The Macro should probably contain the operations from the answer provided by LưuVĩnhPhúc, though.

Comment: i think my solution fit Macondo question,you can do nearly everything with Marco

Comment: 1. He wants to delete the *current* line, not 10 lines. 2. Pressing down 10 times just make the selection to some position on the 10th line. It doesn't select the **whole** 10 lines

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd> -- selects the entire line after the cursor.

Comment: That is not what it is asked.

Comment: It's OK for selecting an entire line, *if the cursor is already at the start of the line.* Consider to add the key *Home* in front of the shortcut in your answer.

Comment: this is no different than my answer 3 years before, and it's also less correct

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> if the cursor is at the end of the line.
Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>, if the cursor is at the beginning of the line.

OR press <kbd>Home</kbd> key to get to the start of the line, and then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>.

OR press <kbd>End</kbd> key to get to the end of the line, and then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>.

Comment: isn't that the same as what I answered above?