# How do I copy a whole line in Notepad++ without selecting it before with a shortcut?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++

I would expect pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> without having selected anything to copy the whole line where the cursor is. Unfortunately this is not the case.

Is there a way to change this behaviour?

Of course I am aware of how to select a whole line pressing <kbd>Home</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> or triple-clicking the line and then copying it to clipboard.

But what I want is just pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> without having selected anything in the line. Why is this default behaviour not implemented in my favorite editor?

Comment: why do you think it's not available? Did you try the shortcut mapper and search for "copy"? Nowadays it's `Shift+Ctrl+X` by default

Comment: CTRL-D will duplicate the current row, in case you are meaning that with copy.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Is there a keyboard shortcut to select the entire current line in Notepad++?](https://superuser.com/questions/947296/is-there-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-select-the-entire-current-line-in-notepad)

there is the answer of your question, seems ctrl+shift+X does the copy line has wish to.

Comment: I've already voted to close this question with that one several minutes before

Answer (score 0):

#### "Why is this default behaviour not implemented in my favorite editor?"

> I would expect pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> without having selected anything to copy the whole line where the cursor is. Unfortunately this is not the case.

Why do you expect this? As far as I know this is not the default behaviour for any windows application.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in a Windows application requires a selection of something to be copied.

It is not default behaviour for Notepad++ and the developers chose not to implement this functionality.

You can either [make a feature request](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues) or [download the source code](https://github.com/donho/notepad-plus-plus) and add this feature yourself.

Comment: This is _very_ common behavior in Windows programmer's editors, including Visual Studio, Visual Studio Code, UltraEdit and IntelliJ IDEA (and all the other JetBrains IDEs). And if you're asking "why do you expect this?" I would ask the opposite question: why would you expect Ctrl+C to do nothing at all when it could do the very useful thing that many programmer's editors already support?