# Copy current line to clipboard in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, clipboard

Select an entire line of text, and <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd> copies the line to the clipboard. Great!

But is there a Notepad++ <kbd>CTRL+??</kbd> shortcut to copy the current line to the clipboard without actually having to select any text (or needing to fiddle with <kbd>Home</kbd> then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a keyboard shortcut to select the entire current line in Notepad++?](https://superuser.com/questions/947296/is-there-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-select-the-entire-current-line-in-notepad).... Ctrl+Shift+x while the cursor is on any line and it'll copy that entire line to the clipboard and then you can paste accordingly.

Comment: @ITThugNinja: Aha, well spotted. `Ctrl + Shift + X` does what I need. That other question is not the same, and the answers are specific to that question. Searching for the answer to this question may not find that question, so the link is helpful.